# How do AND and OR operators work in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I tried the following command in bash

```
echo this || echo that && echo other
```

This gives the output

```
this
other
```

I didn't understand that!

My dry run goes this way :

1. `echo this || echo that && echo other` implies `true || true && true`
2. Since, `&&` has `more precedence` than `||`, the second expression evaluates first
3. Since, `both are true`, the `||` is evaluated which also gives true.
4. Hence, I conclude the output to be:

> that
>
> other
>
> this

Being from a Java background where `&&` has more precedence than `||`, I am not able to relate this to bash.

Any inputs would be very helpful!

Comment: note both like same precedence to left to right associative

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [`man bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists)

> 3.2.3 Lists of Commands
>
> A list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the operators ‘;’, ‘&’, ‘&&’, or ‘||’, and optionally terminated by one of ‘;’, ‘&’, or a newline.
>
> Of these list operators, **‘&&’ and ‘||’ have equal precedence**, followed by ‘;’ and ‘&’, which have equal precedence.

So, your example

```
echo this || echo that && echo other
```

could be read like

```
(this || that) && other
```

Answer (score 8):

In bash, `&&` and `||` have *equal* precendence and associate to the left. See [Section 3.2.3 in the manual for details](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists).

So,  your example is parsed as

```
$ (echo this || echo that) && echo other
```

And thus only the left-hand side of the or runs, since that succeeds the right-hand side doesn't need to run.

Answer (score 4):

Boolean evaluation in `bash` is short-circuit: `true || false` will never evaluate the `false` operand, because the `true` operand is enough to determine the outcome of the operation. Likewise, `false && true` will not evaluate the `true` operand, because it cannot change the value of the expression.

Boolean evaluation in `bash` is actually used *mainly* for controlling the conditional evaluation of the operands, not their order. Typical usage is `do_foo || do_bar_if_foo_fails` or `do_foo && do_bar_only_if_foo_has_succeeded`.

In no situation will your `echo that` command be executed, because the `echo this` is `true` and determines the value of the entire `echo this || echo that` sub-expression.

Answer (score 3):

From [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> Of these list operators, && and || have equal precedence, followed by
>   ; and &, which have equal precedence.

So your output is expected.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've already figured it out.  Operator precedence doesn't work like that in `bash`.  Everything just goes left to right in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Let's explain what this does:

```
echo this || echo that && echo other
```

`echo this || echo that` -> `echo that` only if `echo this` FAILS.

`&& echo other` -> `echo other` only if the command before `&&` SUCCEEDS.

So basically:

`echo this`---> SUCCESS ----> `echo that` ----> is not executed since `echo this` succeeded ---> `echo other` ---> is executed cause `echo this || echo that` was executed correctly.