# || && opperators print both the truth and false outputs

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I'm working on a script that will count the number of rows in my file and if there is less than 1 row it will not run my "blender" script.

Can someone confirm what I am misunderstanding about the operators work as it runs my script regardless of if it's true or not, but oddly not the echo command before it.

Bonus point if someone can tell me how I can have the variables within the statement, without the need to assign them as variables. I've tried a lot of different ways but every time it spits out errors.

### Code

```
placement="$(wc -l array/placement-array.tsv | awk '{print $1}')"
advertiser="$(wc -l array/advertiser-array.tsv | awk '{print $1}')"

[ $placement -lt 1 ] && echo "This email doesn't appear to have placement" || echo "this file has a placement, running placement script" && ./scripts/placement_blender.sh && echo "placement script run"
[ $advertiser -lt 1 ] && echo "This email doesn't appear to have advertiser" || echo "this file has a advertiser, running advertiser script" && ./scripts/advertiser_blender.sh && echo "advertiser script run"
```

### Output

> ```
>     + awk {print $1}
>     + wc -l array/placement-array.tsv
>     + placement=1
>     + awk {print $1}
>     + wc -l array/advertiser-array.tsv
>     + advertiser=0
>     + [ 1 -lt 1 ]
>     + echo this file has a placement, running placement script 
>     this file has a placement, running placement script
>     + ./scripts/placement_blender.sh
>     + echo placement script run 
>     placement script run
>     + [ 0 -lt 1 ]
>     + echo This email doesn't appear to have advertiser 
>     This email doesn't appear to have advertiser
>     + ./scripts/advertiser_blender.sh
>     + echo advertiser script run 
>     advertiser script run
> ```

Comment: Side note: if you use `wc -l < file` instead of `wc -l file`, you get just the number of lines, no file name.

Comment: @BenjaminW.confirming that's intentional as I wanted to have the number be treated in the first part of the if statement

Comment: Never use `&&` *after* `||`. Use a proper `if/then/elif/else/fi` or some similar construct if one test isn't enough for your logic.

Comment: @PaulHodges gotcha, I found that link that was posted on this thread a little bit ago (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836768/echo-with-and) very helpful. Essentially I should swap my statements around so there is only one "command" after `| |`

Comment: Yes; I meant to point out how you can skip the `awk` statement by using redirection. Compare the output of `wc -l < file` and `wc -l file`.