# combining || and && in bash

Tags: bash, operators, echo

When I execute this in the following line in my shell

```sh
echo this || echo that && echo other
```

The output is:

```sh
this
other
```

Now I don't understand how `echo other` is executed, because `echo that` does not return a successful exit status because it is not executed. The `&&` operator only executes the right command when the left command exits successfully.

Does this mean the && operator will execute the righthand command if anything on the left side exits successfully?

Comment: Duplicate of [echo with || and &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836768/echo-with-and)

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite that example as:

```
(echo this || echo that) && echo other
```

You say `echo that` does not return a successful exit status, but rather, it doesn't return anything at all - it is not executed. So the expression `(echo this || echo that)` has a successful result (the return of  `echo this`), which makes `echo other` be executed.

A good example for this situation is just running `echo this || echo that` - it has a return value of 0, as such, not executing `echo that` does not turn it into a failure.

Comment: No problem! If the question was solved, please accept an answer, either this one or another you have found more thorough.

Answer (score 3):

Using both `||` and `&&` in the same line of code, is not a good practice, while it might work on some cases/situations, that does not mean it will work on all cases.

see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3

Always use an `if` statement if you feel like doing a short circuit.

Command grouping is a work around if you really need to do that, using the `{ }`

```sh
echo this || { echo that && echo other; }
```

Comment: The man page explicitly says that `||` and `&&` have equal precedence. This only meaningful interpretaton of that is that there is a well-defined sequence of operations from left to right in the event that they are used together. When you say "will not work on all cases", this does not mean that the behaviour will be undefined, but simply that the effect may be different from what is expected if the programmer does not properly understand the semantics.

Comment: Thank  you for that wonderful comment. What I'm trying to say is avoid using both `||` and `&&` in no particular order to avoid surprises, bugs etc. I did not mention about any precedence.

Comment: Okay, well my point was essentially that whether it "works" depends on what it is that the programmer was trying to achieve. There may be examples where you wish to run one command but with a fallback if it failed, and then do something else provided that either the first command or the fallback succeeded. But yes I can accept that your suggestion of command grouping (in this case `{ command1 || command2; } && command3`) would add some clarity even if technically unnecessary in this situation.

Comment: Similarly `command1 && command2 || command3` in order to do `command1` unconditionally, followed by `command2` but only if `command1` succeeded, but do `command3` as a fallback if either 1 or 2 failed. And similarly, yes I can see that it may be worth putting in explicit command grouping for clarify.

Comment: Well, it's not just about clarity but a good practice to use braces `{ }` for command groupings when it involves short circuit (combining && and ||  in no particular order) in one line. Take for example some destructive commands such as `rm`, `dd` `shred` and the likes, using the short circuit construct on those commands, one might end up with a deleted/broken system/files etc.

Answer (score 1):

The effect of:

```
command1 || command2
```

is as follows:

- If `command1` returns zero: `command2` is not executed, and overall return value is 0.
- If `command1` returns non-zero: `command2` is executed, and overall return value is that of `command2`.

It is somewhat analogous to short-circuit evaluation of an "or" operator in various programming languages (e.g. `a || b` in C) except that a "true" value is a zero (i.e. successful) exit status rather than a non-zero value of an expression.

Given that the `echo` statements return 0, this means that the effect of

```
echo this || echo that
```

is to execute `echo this` but not `echo that`, and to have an overall exit status of 0.

Given this, and that the `||` and `&&` are treated with equal precedence (so are evaluated from left to right), the command sequence:

```
echo this || echo that && echo other
```

will also cause `echo other` to be executed (because `foo && bar` will execute `bar` if `foo` returned 0).

So, `command1 || command2 && command3` is valid, but if should **not** be read as meaning:

> (a) Run `command1`. Then if `command1` failed then run `command2` but if `command1` succeeded then run `command3`.

Instead, it should be read as:

> (b) Run `command1`. If `command1` failed then run `command2`. If *either* (`command1` succeeded) *or* (`command1` failed but `command2` succeeded), then run `command3`.

(where "succeeded" means exited with zero status).

If the intention is as described in (a), then this should instead be implemented using:

```
if ! command1 ; then command2 ; else command3 ; fi
```

or

```
if command1 ; then command3 ; else command2 ; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`&&` and `||` have the same order of precedence.

So `echo this || echo that` occurs first and then `&& echo other`.