# Bash script in Makefile Succeeds even after Error

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling, makefile

I have a `command` that runs in my Makefile that is succeeding regardless if my `command` succeeds or errors out.

This is my Makefile:

```
all:
   command || echo "command Failed" && false;
```

If the command is successful. The echo "command Failed" is not printed out and when the commmand errors out it does echo "command Failed". Which is the expect output. However, my Makefile doesn't stop executing and doesn't throw an error. How do I get my `command` to print the error logs, "command Failed" and the Makefile to throw and error?

Comment: I can't reproduce. If I use `false` as the command, I get `make: *** [all] Error 1`

Comment: I get the opposite problem. Make reports an error even if the command is successful.

Comment: If the problem is error-despite-success like Barmar suggested then probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365548/combining-and-in-bash

Comment: What your script says is "if `command` fails run the echo command and then exit with the exit code generated by `echo`; if `command` succeeds then run `false` and exit with the exit code generated by `false`".  Since `echo` always returns success and `false` always returns failure, what your script does is echo `command failed` if the command fails, then exit with success, and not echo anything and exit with failure if `command` succeeds

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what you WANT to happen.  If what you want to happen is that the message should be printed and the shell exits with failure if `command` fails, and nothing should be printed and the shell exits with success if `command` succeeds, you can write `command || { echo "command failed"; false; }`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem, I get the opposite: `make` reports an error and stops when the command succeeds. The reason is that `&& false` always executes, because `&&` and `||` are left-associative. Your command is equivalent to

```
{ command || echo "command failed"; } && false
```

The first command group always succeeds, because either `command` succeeds or `echo` succeeds.

Use explicit command grouping to ensure that `false` only executes when the first command fails.

```
all:
    command || { echo "command Failed"; false; }
```

Or just use a normal `if` statement rather than using logical operators for control flow:

```
all:
    if ! command; then \
        echo "command failed"; \
        false; \
    fi
```

Comment: Just to be clear, `&& false` doesn't _always_ execute.  It executes exactly when `command` succeeds.  Also, in your second example you are missing semicolons after the `echo` and `false` statements; what you have there is a syntax error in the shell.

Comment: @MadScientist If it only executes when the command succeeds, why does the recipe fail when the command fails?

Comment: Oops you're right; I misread this as `xxx && yyy || zzz` instead of `xxx || yyy && zzz`

Comment: @MadScientist Yeah, that's the usual way people condense `if x then y else z` into logical operators. But this is `if !x then y; z`

Answer (score 0):

For proper error-handling and readability, you can try this :

```
.ONESHELL:
SHELL = /bin/bash
all:
    @trap 'this_command=$$BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG
    trap 'ret=$$?; echo "[$$this_command] failed"; exit $$ret' ERR
    echo First command succeeds
    false Second command will cause error
    echo Third command is not reached
```

Output :

```
First command succeeds
[false Second command will cause error] failed
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 1
```