# How to exit a bash script if a disk is not mounted

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am having trouble exiting a backup script if the backup drive is not mounted.

My best attempt so far was:

```bash
findmnt $BACKUP_DRIVE >/dev/null || (
   echo "Drive not found." && exit 1
   )
```

This works reliably to execute the script if the device is mounted, but only the error message is echoed, the script does not get exited. So I tried the following which yields exectly the same results:

```bash
findmnt $BACKUP_DRIVE >/dev/null || (
   echo "Drive not found."
   exit 1
   )
```

What troubles me about it is that if I replace `exit 1` with `echo test` in both examples above, the second `test` message is echoed as expected.

I also tried to use a `! [ findmnt "$BACKUP_DRIVE" >/dev/null ]; then` statement but this is not working at all complaining about a `unary operator expected`.

So I guess I have two questions, why in my first attempts the `echo test` command is executed, but not the `exit 1` command ? And of course, how should I approach this problem to get reliable results ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### (...)

`( command )` creates another shell.

So

```
echo "hello" && (echo "foo" ; exit 0 ; echo "bar") && echo "world"
```

prints `hello`, `foo`, and `world`, not `bar`.
Yet, it doesn't exit the whole script. Only the one spawned by `(...)`. So it doesn't echo `bar`, because it exited the script `(echo "foo" ; exit 0 ; echo "bar")`

What you may do is

```
if findmnt "$BACKUP_DRIVE" >/dev/null
then
   :
else
   exit 1
fi
```

(One way among manys)

### [...]

Another interpretation problem you have with one of your trials is about `[...]` syntax.

`[` is basically a version of `test` program. It is supposed to be used to test some expression. For example `[ "$x" = "12" ]` to test if string `$x` is `12`. It is not part of the `if` syntax.
`if` syntax is `if command; then dosomething; fi`.

`command` being any command (including, but not limited to, `[...]` that is just a command, like any other, with an exit code).

`if` condition will be executed if command's exit code is 0.

Some experiments

```
# [ ... ] is just a command with an exit code
x=12
[ "$x" = "12" ]
echo $? # Echo 0 since previous command succeeded
[ "$x" = "15" ]
echo $? # Echo 1, since previous command failed

# Syntax of if is `if justACommand ...`
if ls / > /dev/null
then
   echo "ls succeded"
fi 
# prints `ls succeeded` since you can (usually) ls /
if ls /nonExistingFile > /dev/null
then
   echo "ls succeeded"
fi
# prints nothing (but an error message from ls since I did not redirect 2>) because ls exit code was 1
```

So, the closest method to your 2nd trial, is simply to remove brackets. You don't want brackets here. It is  a command that can tell you whether a file exist, or whether 2 strings are identical, or... (see `man test` to see how it can do). You already have the command whose exit code tells you whether disk is mounted or not. It is `findmnt`.

```
if ! findmnt "$BACKUP_DRIVE" >/dev/null ; then 
    exit 1
fi
```

And while I am at it the way to do it without if, closest to your first attempt would be

```
findmnt $BACKUP_DRIVE >/dev/null || { echo "Drive not found." >&2; exit 1 ;}
```

(don't forget the last `;`)

(The `>&2` is to write error message on stderr, as suggested by Ed Morton. It is not related to why your code is not working, but well, it is indeed better to write error message on error stream)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did not know about the parenthesis creating a new shell. I was using it as a way to run more than one command if the condition was met; I do not remember where I got this idea from. Simply removing the parenthesis and doing `echo msg && exit 1` exits even if the disk is mounted, and the `if-then` method throws a `unary operator expected` error each time.

Comment: I'd suggest `findmnt "$BACKUP_DRIVE" >/dev/null || { es="$?"; echo "Drive not found." >&2; exit "$es"; }` to have it work regardless of the content of `$BACKUP_DRIVE`, print the error message to `stderr` instead of `stdout`, and preserve whatever exit status `findmnt` exited with to exit your command with that same status in case it's useful to who/whatever is calling your script.

Comment: @lyndhurst Regarding "Simply removing the parenthesis and doing echo msg && exit 1 exits even if the disk is mounted" - right because you're telling it to. `a || b && c` doesn't mean `if a fails then b else c`, it means `if a fails then b; if the last command you ran succeeds then c`. It's not a ternary operator so if `findmnt` fails then you'll `echo msg` and then `exit 1` because `echo msg` (the last command ran) succeeded, while if `findmnt` succeeds you won't `echo msg` but you will still `exit 1` because `findmnt` (the last command ran) succeeded.

Comment: Regarding "the if-then method throws a unary operator expected error" - we'd need to see the full `if-then` construct you actually used to be able to debug/explain that but the code in the answer won't do that, assuming you quote `"$BACKUP_DRIVE"` (always quote your variables, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Comment: @chrslg thanks for the information added, now all the different approaches work fine. You were right, learning bash as I go and off code I read on the internet, I thought that the square brackets were part of the bash `if-statement` syntax. Also you solved my first attempts mistake by pointing to the use of `{ ... ; ... ;}` syntax to execute several commands; what I was originally and wrongly using parenthesis for.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for pointing to the good practice of sending error message to the error stream; I knew all the syntax but never put it together in my own scripts even though I get frustrated sometimes when programs I use in my scripts do not do it. For the rest, my previous comment sums up the problems with both approaches, I was using `()` instead of `{}` to chain commands, and using square brackets in my `if-statement` though it did not belong there. thanks for your help.

Comment: I assumed [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77935454/how-to-exit-a-bash-script-if-a-disk-is-not-mounted/77935510?noredirect=1#comment137396317_77935510) was feedback on you trying the constructs provided in the answer, not additional information about the constructs you had used previously. Please put all information about your question in your question, don't add it as comments where it can't be formatted and could be missed (and could be misunderstood!).

Answer (score 0):

Use `if`. Do not use `||` for control flow. Use `mountpoint` command to check if a path is a mountpoint.

```
if ! mountpoint -q "$BACKUP_DRIVE"; then
    echo "$BACKUP_DRIVE is not a mountpoint"
    exit 1
fi
```

Quote variable expansions. Check your scripts with shellcheck.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. thanks to chrslg's answer, I got the logic working. But I you cared to elaborate, I would be interested in knowing why I should use `if` over `||`, and `mountpoint` over `findmnt`. I came across the `mountpoint -q` while searching to solve my problem, but I did not get why it mattered which one I used.

Comment: Regarding "Do not use || for control flow" - [Assertions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development)) exist in many languages and that construct provides assertions for shell. I frequently use them when running commands that I don't expect to fail but need to make **sure** I don't continue processing if they do, e.g. `tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1` or `cd dir || exit 1` or ensuring values are populated as expected `(( foo > 20 )) || exit 1`, etc. (often with helpful messages printed - `whatever || { es="$?"; echo "the sky is falling" >&2; exit "$es"; }`)

Comment: In this case I think that's what the OP is doing - just asserting that the drive is mounted before continuing trying to use it.

Comment: @lyndhurst For the first one (`if` over `||`) I would say that it is an aesthetic problem. I, myself, would easily use `||` in your case also. But for more complex control-flow, that is using `||` and `&&` for their side effect (lazy or and and), so it might be harder for a human reader to understand what is the intention (not evaluating a complex condition, but doing some conditional execution). But that is a matter of personal judgement

Comment: (especially if you code for yourself. Obviously, I wouldn't code the same way for a strictly personal script that I know nobody else would ever see; for a script that I may include later in an open-source project, or that I share with coworkers; or for a script that I intend to distribute to my students. In the latter situation I would never use `A||B` if I meant to say "if A fails then execute B", unless I am precisely trying to teach `||` and lazy-logic.

Comment: For `findmnt` vs `mountpoint`, it is also a aesthetic consideration I guess. `mountpoint` purpose is to do exactly what you want to do: check if something is mounted. While `findmnt` purpose is to "find" them (from their mountpoint or device). Both work. Both are supposed to exit with the exit code as you expect. It is in both case documented. So there is nothing wrong with your usage. But maybe a human reader would have less hard time understanding your intend if you use `mountpoint` rather than `findmnt`. Wouldn't bother me, for sure, but I guess that is the reason.

Comment: Also, because `findmnt` prnts more things, it is very very slightly slower. 3.6 ms per call on my machine vs 3.3 ms per call (once removed the noise). I don't think that is meaningful for your probable usage.

Comment: @chrslg The reason to use `if` over `||` isn't merely aesthetics, it is because of [how conditionals are evaluated in complex cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365548/combining-and-in-bash). It's extremely difficult to write `a && b || c` in a way that `b` and `c` are guaranteed to be mutually exclusive and the code you do write is more likely to be fragile or error-prone in some way. `if a ; then b ; else c ; fi` on the other hand can trivially handle that complexity and more.

Comment: `||` and `&&` are fine for simple cases like `cmd || die`, but once you begin combining conditionals or trying to group conditional commands together it is much easier to use `if`.

Comment: Waow, thank you @chrslg for all the explanations, they were very helpful. For the use of `||` over a classic `if` statement I think I will stick with it since it is a small personal script, and I find it does look better for a simple check like this one. For the `mountpoint` vs `findmnt`, the former seems more appropriate in the light of your very detailled comments. I actually learned quite a few things from a single non essential line in a script ! Thanks again.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you for pitching in again, I think you got my intent right, and all I am doing is a simple assertion, so as I commented in more details above, I will stick with the simple one liner for that particular check.